# Linux log file wildcard in SCOM

Tags: linux, postgresql, scom

I want to monitor a log file that's on Linux on SCOM.

The log is from postgresql. The path is `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postgresql-2017-08-21.log`.

The thing is, that if I put that string it works, but I can't seem to make it work with wildcards for the dates.

I already tried `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-%Y-%m-%d.log` but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

SCOM does not provide the same log file monitoring capabilities on Linux than on Windows. On Linux it can only monitor one file from a monitoring template, there is no support for file patterns. I can recommend using one of the following ways to workaround this limitation (in increasing complexity order):

1. Make the application log to one file (by disabling log file rotation, or by using a script that appends the log into a separate file for SCOM monitoring)
2. Transfer the log files to a Windows server which has SCOM Agent installed and monitor the files from there. Don't forget that the files need to be converted from UNIX line endings (\n) to DOS/Windows line endings (\r\n).
3. Develop some script-based (i.e.: Python) solution that follows the log file rotation. While this can cover all future requirements (i.e.: alerting for more patterns in the logs), it adds a **lot** of complexity to the system

Answer (score -1):

you can try :

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
```

Comment: When I put that on the log file path it says "The log file path contains an unsopported character"... it does not support the ( ) characters.

Comment: $ echo /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-2017-08-21.log

Comment: whene I try :                                                                                                echo /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log                 I get :                                                                                                                  /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-2017-08-21.log

Comment: [root@xxxxxxxx prueba]# echo /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postresql-2017-08-21.log

The thing is, that scom (operation manager) does not support that string.

Comment: It only work if I hardcode the file name... but that would only work for one day, its not dynamic